# Closed form of $\dfrac{1}{s!}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}^s)$ and $N$-gon in a graph

Tags: calculus, matrices, graph-theory, algorithms, trace

What is the closed form of $\dfrac{1}{s!}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_n^s)$?

Where $\mathbf{A}_n\in\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$ is a generic adjacency matrix of an  undirected graph and $s\in\mathbb{N}$

$\mathbf{A}_n=(a_{ij})_{ij}=\begin{cases}0&\text{if }i=j\\1\text{ or }0&\text{if }i\neq j\end{cases}\qquad$ and $\mathbf{A}_n^{\top}=\mathbf{A}_n$

I found this pattern for $s=3$:
$$\mathbf{A}_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{12}&0&a_{23}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_3^3)=a_{12} a_{13} a_{23}$$

---

$$\mathbf{A}_4=\begin{pmatrix}
0&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}\\
a_{12}&0&a_{23}&a_{24}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&0&a_{34}\\
a_{14}&a_{24}&a_{34}&0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_4^3)=a_{12} a_{13} a_{23} + a_{12} a_{14} a_{24} + a_{13} a_{14} a_{34} + a_{23} a_{24} a_{34}=\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_3^3)+ a_{12} a_{14} a_{24} + a_{13} a_{14} a_{34} + a_{23} a_{24} a_{34}$$

---

$$\mathbf{A}_5=\begin{pmatrix}
0&a_{12}&a_{13}&a_{14}&a_{15}\\
a_{12}&0&a_{23}&a_{24}&a_{25}\\
a_{13}&a_{23}&0&a_{34}&a_{35}\\
a_{14}&a_{24}&a_{34}&0&a_{45}\\
a_{15}&a_{25}&a_{35}&a_{45}&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_5^3)=a_{12} a_{13} a_{23} + a_{12} a_{14} a_{24} + a_{12} a_{15} a_{25} + a_{13} a_{14} a_{34} + a_{13} a_{15} a_{35}+...\\
a_{14}a_{15}a_{45}+a_{23} a_{24} a_{34} + a_{23} a_{25} a_{35} + a_{24} a_{25} a_{45} + a_{34} a_{35} a_{45}$$
$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_5^3)=\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_4^3)+ a_{12} a_{15} a_{25} + a_{13} a_{15} a_{35}+ a_{14}a_{15}a_{45} + a_{23} a_{25} a_{35} + a_{24} a_{25} a_{45}+ a_{34} a_{35} a_{45}$$

---

So in general
$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_{n}^{3})=\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_{n-1}^{3})+\sum_{1\leq i< j<n}a_{ij}a_{in}a_{jn}$$

I concluded that:

$$\frac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_n^3)=\sum_{k=3}^{n}\sum_{1\leq i< j<k}a_{ij}a_{ik}a_{jk}$$

---

**Is it correct?**

Note that $k=3,...,n$ because $\dfrac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_1^3)=\dfrac{1}{6}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_2^3)=0$

Easier to notice was the case for $s=2$:
$$\frac{1}{2}\text{trace}(\mathbf{A}_n^2)=\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}a_{ij}^2$$

---

The problems start for $s\geq 4$, is there any formula to calculate it in an "efficient" way (I have to apply it to a program in C++ language)

Technically for $s=2$ I have the number of edges, for $s=3$ I have the number of triangles

Is it correct that for $s=N$ I have the number of $N$-gon?

Comment: You are probably looking for the number of cliques of size $s$ in the graph.

Comment: @Youem Exactly, I meant them

Comment: Do you want to prove that the number that you are looking for is the number of cliques?

Comment: No no, I supposed that that number is the number of cliques because for s=2 and s=3 it represents them, but I don't know if there is a different formula for $s>3$

Comment: I don't think there is a closed form formula to compute it and for best of my knowledge the best algorithm to compute the number of cliques of size $s$ has a complexity of $\mathcal O\left(n^s(n+m)\right)$ where $n$ and $m$ are the number of vertices and edges.